# Generate OpenApi 3 with annotation SpringBoot v3

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin

I'm trying to generate a file openapi.yaml with the correct annotation and with the "springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin:1.4"
The project is structured in a hexagonal architecture ande the dependency and plugin are on a submodule of rest package.
I have tested this plugin in the step with a simple architecture and it worked but with this hexagonal architecture not work.

I'm ussing this dependencys:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

And I have this plugin:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>integration-test</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
      <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs</apiDocsUrl>
      <outputFileName>openapi.yaml</outputFileName>
      <outputDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDir>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And when I execute "generate" of the plugin, this returned this:

```
[INFO] --- springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin:1.4:generate (default-cli) @ server-api-openapi ---
[ERROR] An error has occured
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0 (Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect (Net.java:579)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect (Net.java:568)
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect (NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:633)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:583)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect (NetworkClient.java:183)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer (HttpClient.java:531)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer (HttpClient.java:636)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init> (HttpClient.java:279)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New (HttpClient.java:384)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New (HttpClient.java:406)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient (HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect (HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect (HttpURLConnection.java:1057)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode (HttpURLConnection.java:529)
    at org.springdoc.maven.plugin.SpringDocMojo.execute (SpringDocMojo.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: You must add two execution goals as pre and post integration tests to the spring-boot-maven-plugin: start and stop. The springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin needs spring-boot to start a local server to produce the docs as it is mean to operate at runtime.